# set charset in rails application

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, apache, character-encoding

I'm trying to setup my charset in a html view in a RoR application.
I configured already the charset by meta equiv tag:
**meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" **

It didn't work, so i tried to change my .htaccess (its a RoR application running under apache) but here is my problem. Normally i could use the following statement:
**AddType 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' html**

But the problem is that, as everybody knows, RoR has no "file extension" and that breaks this .htaccess solution. Anybody knows another way to set a charset in a layout template or view ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have your Rails application set the `Content-type` header, and then you won't need to worry about what Apache is doing.

```
response.headers['Content-type'] = 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
```

You may also want to add

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

to the page itself, so that if someone saves it to disk, it will load with the correct charset.

Comment: can i set it at application controller to make it availabe to all controllers ? Because i'm having problem with characters at the views/layout/application.rhtml

Comment: Thanks, I needed that. @VP, you can put it in a before_filter and I think you can put one of those in the application_controller.rb

Answer (score 2):

I added a function like that, but that still not working i have ç ~ codes in my application.rhtml that are not working.

```
before_filter :configure_charsets 

# Configuring charset to UTF-8 
def configure_charsets 
   headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html; charset=UTF-8"     
end
```

I added as well meta http-equiv html tag and a .htaccess parameter AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

That's still not working, any other tip?

Answer (score 0):

Just set :encoding => 'utf-8' after template name like this:

```
respond_to do |f|
  f.pdf do
    render :pdf => 'path_to_template_file', :encoding => 'utf-8'
  end
end
```